How to detect background and gender(man,women) using TensorFlow.js?
I am trying to create a Web app where user provide a photo and the app should detect the object also gender if he/she of the image and the backgroud. I can detect object by TensorFlow.js object detection but I cannot find any way to detect the background and gender.
here are a example:
If user give a photo where a man standing beside a street then I have to detect that the person is and also detect the person is a man or women also I have to detect the background here the street. How can i do it? any idea?
I am trying Realtime Semantic Segmentation in the browser for gender detection but isn't succed yet.
But I have no idea how can i detect the background or area.
